# Spring-mvc along with DWR

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, dwr

**Can anyone provide me anything about integration of "spring-mvc" with "DWR" in reverse ajax functionality?**

Answer (score 2):

Well this is something new for me. I can see DWR website has enough information about this.
Check out this [link](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/integration/spring.html).

Comment: First of all, thank you. But I have referred that. I need a complete example if any available.

Comment: Buddy, i guess you did not see the link carefully. Anyways watch this  [link](http://www.butterdev.com/dwr/2009/12/dwr-3-x-and-spring/).

Comment: I referred that also. But i need piggybacking with reverse ajax. Can you suggest me anything?

Comment: After a lil bit of googling, i could find [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-reverseajax1/#download). It contains Servlet example of Polling, piggybacking. See if its helpful !!

Comment: Hi the link which you have sent are using comet not DWR and also i dont want to go for long polling i need piggybacking where server automatically pushes the data to browser

Comment: did you download `reverse_ajaxpt1_source.zip` whose link is given on that page. The zip file contains all the examples.